# WebSocket Connection failed: error in connection establishment

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, peer, peerjs

The following code is client and server side code to use webRTC connection. It's working perfectly in localhost. when i deployed to linux shared hosting server., it's getting error.

This is my server side code.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var ExpressPeerServer = require('peer').ExpressPeerServer;

var app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app);

var options = {
    debug: true,
    key: 'peerjs',
    allow_discovery: true,
    ssl: {
        key: '',
        cert: ''
    },
    proxied: true
};
var expressPeerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, options);

app.use('/api', expressPeerServer);
app.use('/', express.static('.'));

app.use('/list', function (req, res) {
    return res.json(Object.keys(expressPeerServer._clients.peerjs));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Basic-ss live at', port);
});

expressPeerServer.on('connection', function (id) {
    console.log('Peer connected with id:', id);
});

expressPeerServer.on('disconnect', function (id) {
    console.log('Peer %s disconnected', id);
});
```

the following is the client side code for connect peer.

```
initPeer(peerId) {
        this.peer = new Peer(peerId, {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 8080,
            path: '/api',
            key: 'peerjs',
            debug: 3,
            config: {
                'iceServers': [
                    { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
                ]
            }
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.currentPeerId = this.peer.id;
            if (this.currentPeerId !== null) {
                isPeerConnected = true;
            } else {
                isPeerConnected = false;
            }
            console.log('Current Peer ID', this.currentPeerId);
        }, 4000);
    }
```

this code is working perfectly in localhost. 
this is the code i am uploading in server.

```
this.peer = new Peer(peerId, {
            host: '',  ===> my domain name here.
            port: 8080,
            path: '/api',
            key: 'mebstelemedclinic',
            debug: 3,
            config: {
                'iceServers': [
                    { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
                    {
                        url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
                        credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
                        username: '28224511:1379330808'
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
```

if use the same server code and the above client side code., it's getting connection error.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.in:8080/api/peerjs?key=peerjs&id=LY42201PH-yKy04f-ygqZJhqrBmezG6&token=n42tatqqn9e' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

i was struck at this point from long time. Help me how can i overcome this error. thank you.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the code below to your path  nano site_name in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`:

```
location  {       
  proxy_pass Ip address;         proxy_http_version 1.1;         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;         proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";         proxy_set_header Host $host;     }
```

Comment: i have similar issue, here is my question,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65102311/convert-nginx-conf-to-apache-conf-for-proxypass?noredirect=1#comment115422862_65102311